# Refresh UIView with Data From Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, uiview, refresh

On my main page I have created 'cards' that display info saved to Parse.

A user can swipe a card away to reveal a new one behind it.

Here's what I am trying so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     [self displayProfileInfo];

     // I am manually setting NUM_CARDS for now (this needs to be changed to the array of how many objects are in my Parse table though 
     self.cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:NUM_CARDS];

     for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARDS; i++)
     {
         self.cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-150, self.view.center.y-160, 300, 360)];

         self.cardView.front.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
         self.cardView.back.layer.backgroundColor = self.cardView.front.layer.backgroundColor;

         [self.cards addObject:self.cardView];
     }

     for (UIView * view in self.cards)
     {
         [self.view addSubview:view];
     }

     self.originalPoint = self.view.center;
}

- (void)displayProfileInfo
 { 
     PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"]; 
     [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"]; [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(NSArrayobjects, NSError error) {
       if (error)
       {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       } 
       else
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
           {
               self.profileObject = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

               PFFile * imageFile = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
               NSURL * imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];
               NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileURL];
               self.cardView.profilePicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

               self.cardView.nameLabel.text = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"fullName"];
               self.cardView.locationLabel.text = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"location"];
           }

       }
}]; }
```

I call this method at viewDidLoad and the first object in my table is displayed in the first card.

When I swipe it away, the next card will not load any data.

What's the best way to get the cards to load in the next available information?

EDIT:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    self.cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
    {
        self.cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-150, self.view.center.y-160, 300, 360)];

        self.cardView.front.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
        self.cardView.back.layer.backgroundColor = self.cardView.front.layer.backgroundColor;

        [self.cards addObject:self.cardView];
    }

    for (UIView * view in self.cards)
    {
        // **** CRASHES HERE ****
        // -[PFObject superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance is what I get
        [self.view addSubview:view];
    }

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
        {
            self.profileObject = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

            PFFile * imageFile = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
            NSURL * imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileURL];
            self.cardView.profilePicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            self.cardView.nameLabel.text = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"fullName"];
            self.cardView.locationLabel.text = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"location"];
        }

    }
}];
```

Here is the new code, and here is what I see in the console:

> -[PFObject superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

So this still needs resolving:

```
PFQuery * query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    self.cards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.count; i++)
    {
        self.cardView = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-150, self.view.center.y-160, 300, 360)];

        self.cardView.front.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
        self.cardView.back.layer.backgroundColor = self.cardView.front.layer.backgroundColor;

        self.profileObject = [objects objectAtIndex:i];

        PFFile * imageFile = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        NSURL * imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageFile.url];
        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileURL];
        self.cardView.profilePicture.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        self.cardView.nameLabel.text = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"fullName"];
        self.cardView.locationLabel.text = [self.profileObject objectForKey:@"location"];

        [self.cards addObject:self.cardView];

        [self.view addSubview:self.cardView];
    }

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you think that Objective-C's for/in syntax will do type-checking for you, but sadly it won't. You add a bunch of PFObjects that aren't UIViews to self.cards, then you overwrite your self.cardView many times and add it (presumably a UIView subclass) to self.cards. Then you ask self.cards for every object, and add them as all as subviews to self.view, whether they can exist as subviews or not. (PFObjects cannot act as subviews of a UIView)

Your code:

```
for (UIView * view in self.cards) {
    // do something with view
}
```

is going to essentially get run as

```
for (id item in self.cards) {
  // blindly assume it's a UIView
  UIView *view = (UIView *)item;
  // do something with item that's been cast into a UIView
  // since it's not a UIView, *crash right away*
}
```

Because you're using your self.cards list to store both the PFObjects and self.cardView, you're going crash here. I would start by making sure that only cardViews are added as subviews of self.view.

Further, it looks like you're re-writing self.cardView again and again. Without knowing that much more about what you're trying to do, why not create a unique cardView each time through that first `for` loop, and add it to an array of cardViews, then try adding all of those cardviews to your self.view?